# Cumulative distribution function via plt.hist()

Tags: python, matplotlib, distribution

I have data and I want to plot empirical cumulative distribution function. I took a piece of code from [matplotlib official site](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_cumulative.html). They use histogram to plot step function.

```
data = np.array([5, 8, 5, 9, 10, 15, 7, 12, 19, 21, 7, 10, 11,
    13, 18, 20, 20, 14, 15, 15, 21, 3, 8, 13, 14, 14, 15,
    14, 17, 24, 22, 28, 24, 22, 25, 16, 21, 24, 18, 20])

hist_cum, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(data, bins='sturges', density=True,
                                         histtype='step',cumulative=True)
```

Output: [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6G0l.png)

The problem is: there is one '28' in the data. Formula says F(x) = P{X < x}. Strict inequality. That means it can't be 1 on the left of x=28.

I cannot understand how to fix it.

Comment: *"Formula says F(x) = P{X < x}. Strict inequality."*  Where does it say that? It is very common to define F(x) = P{X <= x} (e.g. [this defintion of a CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition)).

Comment: Interesting. In some books (I checked mostly in Russian) there is strict inequality. Also once I was told by prof to rewrite my plot because I had used not strict inequality (it was similar to added image). Do you want to say it has no such big difference between strict and not strict in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.  First, I think your understanding of CDF is shaky.  The CDF plot is 1.0 for all X > max(your data) for an empirical distribution.  Right?  The probability that a random sample from this distribution, X is less than the particular point, x, wayyyy off to the high side of the plot is 1.0.

That said, I think what you are looking to do is control the axis limits of your plot.  Try tinkering with these commands before rendering the plot:

```
plt.xlim(0, 28)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,30,2))
```

Comment: I thought CDF is 1.0 iff X >= max(data). Different inequality sign. Some books say strict inequality, some say not strict. I'm confused

Comment: OK, maybe some misunderstanding about the true question.  First CDF is not strict inequality.  It is F(x) = p{X≤x}.  regarding your graph, if the histogram bar, which is at 1.0 at the value 28 extends below 28, then  yes, you have a problem.  You will need to manually control the bins to ensure there is a "bin boundary" at 28.  look at the documentation for 'bins' in matplotlib on how to do this.